# Running setTimeout and showing log in terminal

Tags: node.js, settimeout

I am trying to show the the log using below code in the terminal, but it is only showing one time, what is the wrong in the code ?

I created a file **time.js** with below code

```
setTimeout(function() { console.log("setTimeout: It's been one second!"); }, 1000);
```

and running the code in terminal like this

```
node time.js
```

the output is given below

```
Apples-MacBook-Pro:s3 apple$ node time.js
setTimeout: It's been one second!
Apples-MacBook-Pro:s3 apple$
```

while I am expecting **setTimeout: It's been one second!** log every minute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `setInterval` method instead:

```
setInterval(function() { console.log("setInterval: It's been one second!"); }, 1000);
```

However, beware that this code is dependent on the event loopback and if you have code that occupies the event loopback for too long, this code may not execute every second as you ideally want it to.

Comment: I'll also add that when running intensive code you can call process.nextTick() so that your other events can trigger.